# Status API is showing server error on apiexplorer

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

> The status API throwing a error while retrieving sync status of
>   QuickBooks (for Windows) entities:

-Server Error.
-404 - File or directory not found.
-The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is 
temporarily unavailable.

> you can check on:
>   http://apiexplorer.developer.intuit.com/V2QBD#api

```
    Consumer Key    : qyprdj6FkwCXWoq9Q8oRYlz33HXfN8
    Consumer Secret : WHElfjFy5ip8C7UGFQdSRnl9hCeDq4fivvyxTnX6
    Access Token    : qyprdY6MP5IbtWk6vXji7p7rjc5YsiWpqRWJxht2kuyNO9Wv
    Access Token Secret : u5qksOlffIN1UwEdo2OPqnkpe3xNFTFRHZMEIXNm

RealmId: 641280550
```

Also the SyncActivity API shows details for account's only.

> I want to resolve WriteBack Errors.

How to resolve this and get the Sync Status and Sync Activity?

Answer (score 1):

The API Explorer is doing a GET instead of a POST. We’ll fix it. 
You should not see this error if you use Fiddler for the Status API.

Answer (score 1):

API Explorer has been fixed, you should now be able to query SyncActivity and SyncStatus